# How to reference common .ts files outside a nextJS project

Tags: javascript, next.js

So I have a NextJS project with folder structure:

```
/common
   |-common1.ts
/root
   |
   tsconfig.json
   package.json
   /src
      |- /app
           |-page.tsx
   /components
   /etc...
```

I have some common .TS files I have stored in /common. They are here because they are referenced by several nextJS projects.

How do I reference these from page.tsx in /app?